# How to get the frequency of pairs of characters in a text?

Tags: java, frequency

I'm trying to get the frequency of each pair of characters from a text. I tried the following code but it does not work. For example, I have the text "whatwh" the pairs are [wh ha at tw] (I have to find those), and I want to have the output

```
Number of Occurrence of 'wh' is 2
Number of Occurrence of 'ha' is 1 etc
```

However, as I said, the following code must have an error because it does not produce any output at all.

The "result" I'm mentioning in the code is the text I'm editing

```
private static void getOccuringChar2(String result) {
        // Create an array of size 256
                int count[] = new int[MAX_CHAR]; 
          
                int len = result.length(); 
              
         // Initialize count array index 
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) 

                    count[result.charAt(i)+result.charAt(i+1)]++; 
                
                
         // Create an array of given String size 
                String ch[] = new String[result.length()]; 
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) 
                { 
                    ch[i] = result.charAt(i)+""+result.charAt(i+1); 
                    int find = 0; 
                    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) 
                    { 
          
        // If any matches found 
                        if (result.charAt(i)+""+result.charAt(i+1) == ch[j])  
                            find++;                 
                    } 
          
                    if (find == 1)  
                        
    System.out.println("Number of Occurrence of " + 
         result.charAt(i)+""+result.charAt(i+1)+ "' is:" + count[result.charAt(i)+result.charAt(i+1)]);
                 }
        
    }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger? Also please add a sample input and expected output to your question.

Comment: @tgdavies i have made an example on my description if this is what you mean, also i didnt understand your question about the debugger

Comment: Have you run your program using a debugger, stepping through it line-by-line to make sure that it is behaving the way you expect?

Comment: Also what I mean by an example is to show the value of the `result` string you are passing to the function and to explain what you expect it to print.

Comment: Check the loops carefully and you would see the troubles: the index i+1 could cause an OutOfBoundaryException...

Comment: As @Joe says, you will get a `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` every time you run this code. Have you in fact never run it?

Comment: @tgdavies Nope. I don't run it but I see it. And what I meant was "...IndexOutOfBoundsException"

Comment: You can get that, if the two characters sum to > 255, but you will always get java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. I was asking the OP whether they had run the code before asking their question (which they clearly haven't. Or if they have they have not told us the error they got)

Comment: @tgdavies Sorry, I've misunderstood your reply. I should get a -1

Comment: @tgdavies yes i did, but i cannot understand where the problem is

Comment: @Joe what do you mean with OutOfBoundaryException.. it does not come up with any errors, it is not doing what is supposed to do

Comment: Im sorry if i dont get you very well im a beginner..

Comment: Plus what I think is happening is that for some reason the `find` never gets the value 1 in order to go to the prints, so maybe the problem is that it cannot see the matches..

Comment: Java (and C/C++ as well) starts to count at 0 and ends with len-1. The i+1 will be equal to len and that is the problem I and tgdavies talked about: indexing is out of the boundary

Comment: @Joe I tried it with len-1 but the problem doesnt go away..

Comment: When I run your code, passing "whatwh", I get: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6 If you are running the code you have shown in your question, you should get the same result. Please post the actual code you are running, including where you call `getOccuringChar2`.

Comment: How is this question different to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66134903/find-pairs-of-characters-from-a-text where you have already accepted an answer?